# How I get common rows in a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, join, subquery, many-to-many

this is my first post on stackoverflow.
I have three tables: user, tag and join_user_tag. It's a basic many-to-many relationship and I have to find the tags in common between a not specified number of users.
How can I find that?

PS: sorry for my english, i'm italian

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverFlow, You can look into Intersect clause of sql to achieve your goal.

Create a table called USER : -

```
CREATE TABLE USER(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);
```

Insert records into USER Table : -

```
INSERT INTO USER VALUES(1,'Tom');
INSERT INTO USER VALUES(2,'Lucy');
INSERT INTO USER VALUES(3,'Frank');
INSERT INTO USER VALUES(4,'Jane');
INSERT INTO USER VALUES(5,'Robert');
```

Create Table TAGS : -

```
CREATE TABLE TAGS(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);
```

Insert Record into TAGS : -

```
INSERT INTO TAGS VALUES(1,'TAG1');
INSERT INTO TAGS VALUES(2,'TAG2');
INSERT INTO TAGS VALUES(3,'TAG3');
INSERT INTO TAGS VALUES(4,'TAG4');
INSERT INTO TAGS VALUES(5,'TAG5');
```

Create Table TAG_USER : -

```
CREATE TABLE TAG_USER(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Tag_Id integer , User_Id Integer);
```

Insert Record into TAG_USER : -

```
INSERT INTO TAG_USER VALUES(1,1, 1);
INSERT INTO TAG_USER VALUES(2,1, 2);
INSERT INTO TAG_USER VALUES(3,1, 3);
INSERT INTO TAG_USER VALUES(4,1, 4);
INSERT INTO TAG_USER VALUES(5,2, 1);
INSERT INTO TAG_USER VALUES(6,2, 2);
INSERT INTO TAG_USER VALUES(7,2, 3);
INSERT INTO TAG_USER VALUES(8,2, 4);
INSERT INTO TAG_USER VALUES(9,3, 1);
INSERT INTO TAG_USER VALUES(10,3, 2);
INSERT INTO TAG_USER VALUES(11,3, 3);
```

Display Records : -

```
SELECT * FROM USER;
SELECT * FROM TAGS;
SELECT * FROM TAG_USER;
```

If you want to match for exactly two users : -

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   t1.TAG_ID 
FROM (SELECT * from TAG_USER where USER_ID in (1)) t1
   INNER JOIN (SELECT * from TAG_USER where USER_ID in (2)) t2 USING(TAG_ID);
```

If you want to match for more users you need to add more inner joins

QUERY TO FIND RECORDS : -

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   t1.TAG_ID 
FROM (SELECT * from TAG_USER where USER_ID in (1)) t1
   INNER JOIN (SELECT * from TAG_USER where USER_ID in (2)) t2 USING(TAG_ID)
   INNER JOIN (SELECT * from TAG_USER where USER_ID in (4)) t3 USING(TAG_ID);
```